# Error using maven profiles

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

I've added two profiles to my application and that how it looks:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <db.username>root</db.username>
                <db.password>root</db.password>
                <db.connectionURL>localhost:3306</db.connectionURL>
                <db.driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</db.driverClass>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <db.username>prodroot</db.username>
                <db.password>prodpass</db.password>
                <db.connectionURL>localhost:3306</db.connectionURL>
                <db.driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</db.driverClass>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

In my jdbc.properties file i changed values like this:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=${db.driverClass}
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:mysql://${db.connectionURL}/dbname
jdbc.username=${db.username}
jdbc.password=${db.password}
```

And here's bean from `spring-container.xml`

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
```

When i try to deploy my application i got following error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'db.driverClass'
```

Structure of project:

[image]

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

**EDITED:**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: Are you activating one of your profiles when running the Maven build?

Comment: manouti, of course, anyway i can make maven clean and then package, error i provided above appears when i run my application using tomcat

Answer (score 1):

The way you have set it up right now, the resources are filtered, but end up in the classpath-root, in this case WEB-INF/classes.

You want to let the [maven-war-plugin do filtering on web-resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html).

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to indicate the value wasn't replaced in the properties file as it complains about `db.driverClass` being unresolvable and not `jdbc.driverClassName`. See what the properties file looks like in the built artefact. It looks like you don't have resource filtering enabled in Maven or you forgot to activate any profiles. 
To enable [resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html), add something like this to your `<build>`:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

This assumes your filtered resources (like your jdbc.properties) reside in the usual `src/main/resources` which if **currently not the case**. I suggest you first move all filtered resources there unless you have a good reason against it, as it is by far the simplest setup. Make sure you do not attempt filtering of binary resources (like images)! Understand that resource filtering (e.g. translating the placeholders into actual values) happens **at build time** so you should be able to see the replaced values in your produced WAR.

Seems like your placeholder resolution in Spring is already configured OK to read the properties file, but just in case, you should have something like this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/jdbc.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>
```

Again, this assumes your jdbc.properties is in the classpath root, which will be satisfied if you put it in `src/main/resources` as it will get copied to `WEB-INF/classes`.
You can also use other paths as well (without the `classpath:` prefix), but I find this the easiest. Understand that placeholder resolution in Spring happens **at run time**, thus you will not get the error until you attempt to access the wired value.

Comment: i've updated my question above and added build section from my pom.xml

Comment: Updated the answer in accordance with your modifications.

Comment: Ok, after your second edit, I see the resources are filtered, but as per @Maarten Winkels, it is important to realize where your resources end up. Unpack and look into the WAR that gets produced to get a better understanding of what happens. As he suggests, you can configure the Maven WAR plugin to include resources from different paths, but you then need to also configure Spring placeholder resolver correctly.